# How to place a Jquery object to html element and vice-versa

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

I am trying to convert my pure JavaScript code to a jQuery code block as per requirements of my professor. The only thing missing is the below.
When I try to use the "thumbs" variable it does not work while in jQuery format. Any light? Please!

Working...
It is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function displayThumbFound(found){ // for week lab 4
    htmlStrFound = "";
    var thumbs = document.getElementById('thumbnails');
    var count = 0;

    // Print columns content
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        // Print lines' content
        for(var j = 0; j < found.length; j++){
            [...]
            }
        thumbs.innerHTML = htmlStrFound;            
    }
}   
});
```

NOT Working...
It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function displayThumbFound(found){ // for week lab 4
    htmlStrFound = "";
    var thumbs = $('#thumbnails');
    var count = 0;

    // Print columns content
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        // Print lines' content
        for(var j = 0; j < found.length; j++){
            [...]
            }
        thumbs.html= htmlStrFound;      
    }
}   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
thumbs.html= htmlStrFound;
```

to

```
thumbs.html(htmlStrFound);
```

Answer (score 1):

.html is not a property it is a function

hence use it as

```
thumbs.html('String');
```